# RegEx/Java - Retrieve values from String

Tags: java, regex

From the below string, I need to retrieve `groupA`, `groupB` & `groupC`

```
String str = "(&(objectCategory=group)(|(cn=groupA) (cn=groupB) (cn=groupC) ))"
```

How can this be achieved using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a lookbehind and lookahead in your regex.

```
(?<=\\(cn=)[^()]*(?=\\))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/9)

Explanation:

- `(?<=\(cn=)` Asserts that the characters going to be matched must be preceded by `(cn=`
- `[^()]` Matches any character not of `(` or `)` zero or more times.
- `(?=\))` Asserts that the matched characters must be followed by a closing bracket `)`

**Code:**

```
String str = "(&(objectCategory=group)(|(cn=groupA) (cn=groupB) (cn=groupC) ))";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\(cn=)[^()]*(?=\\))");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()){
System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

**Output:**

```
groupA
groupB
groupC
```

Comment: Tried your code. Result = '[(&(objectCategory=group)(|(cn=, ) (cn=, ) (cn=, ) (cn=, ) (cn=, ) (cn=, ) (cn=, ) (cn=, ) (cn=, ) (cn=, )))]'

Comment: Yup, works great. Thanks Avinash. Can you explain the difference between your regex and @Nicolas's regex `\\(cn=(.*?)\\)`

Comment: he uses capturing groups. BUt i didn't used that. `\\(cn=(.*?)\\)` , this regex matches `(cn=groupA)` but only captures the groupA. Because what the text to be captured was written in th regex.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Avinash, selecting yours as the Answer, even though Nicolas' solution worked for necessity too.

Answer (score 1):

User `Pattern` and `Matcher`. Search and put in the group 1 whatever (`.*?`) between `(cn=` and `)`:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\(cn=(.*?)\\)").matcher("(&(objectCategory=group)(|(cn=groupA) (cn=groupB) (cn=groupC) ))");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
groupA
groupB
groupC
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, your code works for me :)

Comment: Good, you can call me Nicolas and validate the answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
cn=([^)]*)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/10